# @OneToOne + Table-per-Concrete-Class = exception?

Tags: hibernate, one-to-one, ora-02291

I'm new to Hibernate, and I can't get `@OneToOne` to function in our code.
After much reading, I've constructed an isolates example, and thought to ask the help of the community.

Suppose 3 classes: 1 abstract (Class_A) and 2 inheriting from it (Class_B / Class_C). Class_C has a unidirectional pointer to Class_B.
(I've prepared a diagram but the site wont let me post it :-/).

Notes:

1. Pure Java + Hibernate 3.6.0 Final + Oracle 11g.
2. Inheritance strategy = *Table per Concrete Class*.
3. Developed with `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`.
4. In our code Class_B needs its own table, thus no `@Embeddable`.
5. In our code Class_C is also abstract, not as presented here in the simplified example.

### Code

**Class_A**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Class_A {
    @Id
    public long myId = 0;
}
```

**Class_B**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Class_B")
public class Class_B extends Class_A {
    private String myString = "Hellos - I'm Class_B!";
}
```

**Class_C**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Class_C")
public class Class_C extends Class_A {
    private String myString = "Hellos - I'm Class_C!";

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @NotNull
    private Class_B classB;

    public void setClassB(Class_B classB) {
        this.classB = classB;
    }
}
```

**Hibernate Code**

```
StatelessSession statelessSession = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
Class_C classC = new Class_C();
classC.myId = 92;
Class_B classB = new Class_B();
classB.myId = 8000;
classC.setClassB(classB);

statelessSession.beginTransaction();
statelessSession.insert(classC);
statelessSession.getTransaction().commit();
statelessSession.close();
```

### Problems

1. At `insert(classC)` Hibernate only issues an SQL to insert Class_C. There is no SQL to insert Class_B. I see Class_C's details in Oracle, but Class_B's table is empty.
   Here's the SQL:

   > Hibernate: insert into Class_C (classB_myId, myString, myId) values (?, ?, ?)
2. At `getTransaction().commit()` it explodes with

this:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (NDP.FK9619CF1CAD47EF0F) violated - parent key not found
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:17660)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:771)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
at org.hibernate.impl.StatelessSessionImpl.managedFlush(StatelessSessionImpl.java:333)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
...
```

### Questions Please

1. Why doesn't this work... what am I doing wrong?
2. In our legacy code, the application allocates unique id numbers and have no intention of using generated Ids. Thus `@GenerateValue` for our `@Id` isn't considered. Is this a reason why this fails?
3. Whats the difference between `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` vs. `@OneToOne` + `@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})`?

MUCH thanks!

- Ten_of_a_Kind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the cause is

```
StatelessSession statelessSession = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
```

Try to use a normal `Session` instead:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

`StatelessSession` is a special purpose tool that should be used only in special circumstances. For regular operations you should always use `Session`. From Hibenrate docs:

> Alternatively, Hibernate provides a command-oriented API that can be used for streaming data to and from the database in the form of detached objects. A StatelessSession has no persistence context associated with it and does not provide many of the higher-level life cycle semantics. In particular, a stateless session does not implement a first-level cache nor interact with any second-level or query cache. It does not implement transactional write-behind or automatic dirty checking. **Operations performed using a stateless session never cascade to associated instances.**

Comment: Wow that was fast, thanks for your answer. In the code we are currently not interested in the state that `Session` brings. Consider this as a proof-of-concept that an existing, very old, project can move to hibernate.

Instead of using a `Session` and killing its cache every once in a while, is there no way to have this work with a `StatelessSession` (which really fits the bills atm as a no-SQL-only adaptation)?

Comment: UPDATE: Normal `Session` works, but its not what we need... Were doing loading/saving of large batches and now need mechanisms for killing `Session`'s cache. This could work, but is there no way for a `StatelessSession` to do this? If not - why was it invented in the first place? Is this a `StatelessSession` bug?

Comment: @Ten_of_a_Kind: If you actually need `StatelessSession` in this case and clearly understand what you do, its behaviour is explained in the excerpt above: `StatelessSession` doesn't provide cascading, you need to `insert()` `Class_B` manually.

Comment: axtavt - Dude you rock! I've missed that part of the docs amongst the sea of literature I've swam through these past few days...

Answer (score 0):

Please check Hibernate docs. As stated there:

> Operations performed using a stateless session never cascade to associated instances.
>   http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/batch.html#batch-statelesssession

With **org.hibernate.StatelessSession**, you have deal with object inter-dependencies when inserting objects. That's not the case when you are using a **org.hibernate.Session**.

In this case, you must persist classB object **before** classC object to make it work. Persisting order do counts. If you change the persistence order you will have **org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException**. Choose carefully when to use stateless sessions, as it has no persistence context.

```
statelessSession.beginTransaction();

statelessSession.insert(classB); // <- Persisting classB

statelessSession.insert(classC);
statelessSession.getTransaction().commit();
statelessSession.close();
```

Tested with Hibernate 3.6.0 Final + MySQL 5.0.51a-24